# Extract several different elements of a matrix with one command?

Tags: r, matrix, extract

if you have any matrix .. like for example the one attached. And you only want to extract the elements [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4] and [3,4] ... is there any possibility to do this with only one command?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to extract all the numbers above the diagonal (i.e., the 1.00000s), then you can use a different function without having to specify the positions. For above the diagonal, you can use `upper.tri()`; then for below, you can use `lower.tri()`.

```
m1[upper.tri(m1)]
```

Comment: great! I didnt now about that function .. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

We can create a row/column index as a `matrix` to extract the elements based on the position

```
m1[cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4))]
```